# Upper bound for an exponential sum involving characters of a finite field

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, exponential-sums

Let $q = p^n $ be a prime power, $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_{q} $ 
a primitive element of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and denote by $\chi $ a non-trivial additive character of $\mathbb{F}_{q} $. Set 
$\omega = \exp\lbrace { i\frac{2\pi} {q - 1} } \rbrace $, 
I am looking for an upperbound on the following sum
\begin{equation}
\left\vert \sum _{k=0} ^{q - 2} \omega ^{k^2} \chi (\alpha ^k ) \right\vert.
\end{equation}
If we denote by $\psi _c $ the multiplicative character of 
$\mathbb{F}^* _{q} = \mathbb{F}_{q}\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace =\lbrace \alpha ^0 ,\cdots,\alpha^{q-2}\rbrace$ corresponding to $c\in\mathbb{F}_q ^* $ 
then the sum can be written as 
\begin{equation}
\left\vert \sum _{c\in\mathbb{F}_q^*} \psi _c (c) \chi (c) \right\vert.
\end{equation}
The second sum looks much like a Gaussian sum over finite fields, however in this one the multiplicative character changes as well.

**ps**: The multiplicative character is given by 
$\psi _{\alpha ^l} (\alpha ^k ) = \omega ^{lk} = \exp\lbrace i\frac{2\pi}{q-1} lk \rbrace $ . 
The additive character corresponding to an element $a\in\mathbb{F}_{p^n} $ is given by 
$\chi _a (b) = \exp\lbrace i\frac{2\pi}{p} tr(ab) \rbrace $ for all $b\in\mathbb{F}_{p^n} $, 
where the trace $tr : \mathbb{F}_{p^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p $ is defined by 
\begin{equation}
tr(a) = a+a^p + \cdots + a^{p^{n-1}}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that by an **additive character** you mean

> an **irreducible representation** $\chi_\alpha : \mathbb{F}^n_q \longrightarrow  \mathbb{C}$, i.e. a group homomorphism from the **additive group** $(\mathbb{F}^n_q ,+)$ to the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{C},*)$

which we can prove must all take the form 
\begin{equation}\chi_\alpha : \beta \mapsto \exp\left( {\frac{2\pi i \left\langle \alpha ,\beta \right\rangle }{p  }} \right)\end{equation} where $ \left\langle \alpha ,\beta \right\rangle = \sum_i \alpha_i \beta_i $, see [chapter 4 of Tao](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Additive_Combinatorics/xpimQMtn5-IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) for a proof of some of these statements and see [ch.2 of Serre](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Linear_Representations_of_Finite_Groups/9mT1BwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) or [ch.2 of Fulton & Harris](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Representation_Theory/6TwmBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) for a general (non-abelian) overview of the representation theory perspective on characters. The point is the following

> If we let \begin{equation} f(x) = \begin{cases} q \psi_x(x) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0 \\ \end{cases} \end{equation} then the sum you are considering is equal to the Fourier transform of $f$ *i.e.* \begin{equation}  \hat{f}(\alpha) = \frac{1}{q} \sum_{c \in \mathbb{F} _q } f(c) \chi_\alpha(c) =  \sum_{c \in \mathbb{F} _q^* } \psi_c (c) \chi_\alpha(c) \end{equation} see [definition 4.6 in Tao](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Additive_Combinatorics/xpimQMtn5-IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover).

We apply the Hausdorff-Young inequality [theorem 4.8 in Tao](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Additive_Combinatorics/xpimQMtn5-IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) to get that 
\begin{equation}
 \left(\sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{F} _q }\left| \hat f(\alpha)\right|^{p'} \right)^{\frac{1}{p'}} \leq \left(\sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{F} _q } |f(\alpha)|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}  = q\left( \sum_{c \in \mathbb{F} _q^* } |\psi_c (c) |^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\end{equation}
where the LHS is the $l^{q}$-norm, the RHS is the $l^p$-norm, and $p$ satisfies the following  $p^{-1} +q^{-1} = 1 \land 1 \leq p\leq 2$. Plugging in $p = 2$ we get that

\begin{equation}
 \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{F} _q }\left| \hat f(\alpha)\right|^{2} \leq  q\sum_{c \in \mathbb{F} _q^* } |\psi_c (c) |^2
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to saying that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Var}[\hat f] =  \frac{1}{q}\sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{F} _q }\left| \hat f(\alpha)\right|^{2} \leq  \sum_{c \in \mathbb{F} _q^* } |\psi_c (c) |^2\leq  q-1.
\end{equation}

Finally, if you can prove that at least $n$ many $\alpha$ give a value $  | \hat f(a)| \geq  \sqrt b$ then you get that
\begin{equation}
nb +\sup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{F} _q }\left| \hat f(a)\right|^2 \leq  \sum_{\alpha \in S}\left| \hat f(\alpha)\right|^{2}  + \sup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{F} _q }\left| \hat f(a)\right|^2 \leq  \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{F} _q }\left| \hat f(\alpha)\right|^{2} \leq q(q-1)
\end{equation}

which gives you that the maximum value is at most

\begin{equation}
 \sup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{F} _q }\left|\sum_{c \in \mathbb{F} _q^* } \psi_c (c) \chi_\alpha(c) \right| = \sup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{F} _q }\left| \hat f(a)\right| \leq \sqrt{q(q-1)-nb}
\end{equation}

***Essentially we reduced the problem of finding an upper bound to that of finding a lower bound.***